# If $f$ is holomorphic on open connected subset $D \subset \Bbb{C}$ then $\overline{f(\overline{z})}$ is holo on $D'=\{\overline{z}:z \in D\}$

Tags: complex-analysis

If $f$ is holomorphic on open connected subset $D \subset \Bbb{C}$ then $\overline{f(\overline{z})}$ is holo on $D'=\{\overline{z}:z \in D\}$.

So can I use Cauchy Riemann equations or use showing the limit as $h \rightarrow 0$ of

$$\frac{\overline{f(\overline{z}+h)}-\overline{f(\overline{z})}}{h}$$

exists given the limit for $f$ exists?

Comment: Both approaches work.

Comment: So for the C-R approach, I write $f(x,y)=u(x,y)+iv(x,y)$ where $u_x=v_y, u_y=-v_x$. Then how would I write out $\overline{f(\overline{z})}$? in terms of $u,v$. @MartinR

Comment: could I write $\overline{f(\overline{z})}=u(x,-y)-iv(x,-y)$ and apply the chain rule and use the C-R equations for $f$? @MartinR

Comment: A cheaper approach is to use that [holomorphic functions are analytic and vice versa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analyticity_of_holomorphic_functions).

Comment: @AnneBauval is my solution correct?

Comment: It seems so but I prefer the lazy mine ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $f(x,y)=u(x,y)+iv(x,y)$. Then since $f$ is holomorphic, we have

$$u_x=v_y$$
$$u_y=-v_x.$$

Then write $\bar{f(\bar{z})}=u(x,-y)+-iv(x,-y)$.

Then

$$\frac{\partial u(x,-y)}{\partial x}=u_x(x,-y)$$

and

$$\frac{\partial (-v(x,-y))}{\partial y}= (-1)(-1)v_y(x,-y)=v_y(x,-y)$$

But as $u_x(x,y)=v_y(x,y)$ for all $x,y \in \Bbb{R}$ we conclude that

$$u_x(x,-y)=v_y(x,-y).$$

A similar argument holds to show $u_y(x,-y)=-v_x(x,-y)$ thus $\bar{f(\bar{z})}$ is holomorphic as it satisfies the C-R equations.

Answer (score 0):

If $f$ is holomorphic on $D$ then for any $a\in D$, there exists a small disk $B(a,r)\subset D$ on which $f$ can be expanded as a convergent power series: $$f(z)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n(z-a)^n.$$Hence on $B(\overline a,r)\subset\overline D$, $$\overline{f(\overline z)}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\overline{a_n}(z-\overline a)^n,$$ which proves that $z\mapsto\overline{f(\overline z)}$ is holomorphic on $\overline D.$